# Magento 2 rest api order status always updated to complete

Tags: php, magento2

I want to update order status using Magento 2 REST API, for this purpose i use this api,

```
hostname/magento/index.php/rest/V1/orders
```

and also pass json data in POST request

```
$data_json = [
    'entity'=> [
        'entity_id' => 1,
    'state'=>'processing',
    'status'=>'Processing',
    ]
];
```

after executing above code it always update state and status as completed.
Please specify what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as params, its working. Updated state and status both to processing

```
{
    "entity": {
        "entity_id": 1,
        "state":"processing",
        "status": "processing"
    }
}
```

Check mapping from table `sales_order_status_state`.

Comment: I already use these values but always update value as completed.

Comment: what is the meaning of "Check mapping from table sales_order_status_state"??.

Comment: I already used this in one of my project and its working for me.
In that table we can check which state and status is available.

Comment: total 10 status available in table including "processing".but again no success.

Comment: actually i am doing all right things but order status was already completed and want to change its status to processing.so it always show as completed.

Comment: Is there any pattern that we can update staus more than one order in a single API call?

Comment: But which key prevails, the status or state? Because when I provide the state key it won't accept it, but will return a 200 response if it only has the status one. So I guess the former one is not required. Is that correct?